# Too many fetch faliuers

Tags: hadoop

I have a setup, 2 node hadoop cluster on Ubuntu 12.04 and Hadoop 1.2.1.
While I am trying to run hadoop word count example I am gettig "`Too many fetch faliure error`". I have referred many articles but I am unable to figure out what should be the entries in `Masters`,`Slaves` and `/etc/hosts` file.
My nodes names are "`master`" with `ip` `10.0.0.1` and "slaveone" with `ip 10.0.0.2`.

I need assistance in what should be the entries in masters,slaves and `/etc/hosts` file in both `master` and `slave` node?

Comment: Any reason why you're running 1.2.1? I believe it's deprecated. You should  strongly consider being on the 2.x stack (probably 2.4+)

Comment: since it is a stable version i am using it

Comment: It may be a stable version but it's really really old and is not recommended for use. Try upgrading to a later stable version such as 2.4, 2.5 or 2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're unable to upgrade the cluster for whatever reason, you can try the following:

1. Ensure that your hostname is bound to the network IP and **NOT** 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts`
2. Ensure that you're using only hostnames and not IPs to reference services.
3. If the above are correct, try the following settings:

---

```
set mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps=0.80
set tasktracker.http.threads=80
set mapred.reduce.parallel.copies=(>= 10)(10 should probably be sufficient)
```

Also checkout this SO post: [Why I am getting "Too many fetch-failures" every other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890659/why-i-am-getting-too-many-fetch-failures-every-other-day)

And this one: [Too many fetch failures: Hadoop on cluster (x2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073325/too-many-fetch-failures-hadoop-on-cluster-x2)

And also this if the above don't help: http://grokbase.com/t/hadoop/common-user/098k7y5t4n/how-to-deal-with-too-many-fetch-failures
For brevity and in interest of time, I'm putting what I found to be the most pertinent here.

> The number 1 cause of this is something that causes a connection to get a
>   map output to fail. I have seen:
>   1) firewall
>   2) misconfigured ip addresses (ie: the task tracker attempting the fetch
>   received an incorrect ip address when it looked up the name of the
>   tasktracker with the map segment)
>   3) rare, the http server on the serving tasktracker is overloaded due to
>   insufficient threads or listen backlog, this can happen if the number of
>   fetches per reduce is large and the number of reduces or the number of maps
>   is very large.
>
> There are probably other cases, this recently happened to me when I had 6000
>   maps and 20 reducers on a 10 node cluster, which I believe was case 3 above.
>   Since I didn't actually need to reduce ( I got my summary data via counters
>   in the map phase) I never re-tuned the cluster.

EDIT: Original answer said "Ensure that your hostname is bound to the network IP and 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts`"

Comment: yes, i have tried some permutation and combination to add ip address in /etc/hosts file...but with my configuration ie  nodes names are "master" with ip 10.0.0.1 and "slaveone" with ip 10.0.0.2, what should be my entries in MASTERS, SLAVES and /etc/hosts file please?