# why the reducer in hadoop 1.0.3 very slow

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I'm using hadoop 1.0.3 with java-oracle 7 - 
when I run the word count code in big data nearly 1.5GB size , it take long time  in reducing reach to 10 hours or more just in copying step. 
the system  with 16 node ;one naster and 15 slave each node have :
The cluster summary are as follows:

```
Configured Capacity: 2.17TB
DFS Used: 4.23GB
Non DFS USed:193.74GB
DFS Remaining: 1.98TB
DFS Used%: .19%
DFS Remaining%: 91.09%
Live Nodes: 16
Dead Nodes: 0
Decomissioned Nodes: 0
Number of Under Replicated Blocks: 0
```

[the reducer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quPM7.png)

I try it with 29 mapper and 1 reducer,16 reducer,35 reducer ,56 reducer... the problem is the same and error appear "too many fetch failer "

Answer (score 0):

How many mappers and reducers are being used?
Looks like you are using a very low number of reducers.
Given a low number of reducers, you will observe poor performance.
You need to configure the mappers and reducers according to your context and number of available worker nodes.

Comment: If you have 16 nodes, than it would make sense that you have at least 16 reducers. The defaults provided for you are not always good.

Comment: I increase it to 16 and 35,56 according to the equation (nodes * mapred.tasktracker.tasks.maximum)*{.95 or 1.75}.. but "too many fetch failer " error appear

Comment: You have a network misconfiguration. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978936/too-many-fetch-faliuers

Comment: I see this link before ,but I can't understand the point very will ,or at least how to solve it . my /etc/hosts is like this :
127.0.1.1       justcbuser-virtual-machine

10.242.21.160 master
10.242.21.161 slave1
10.242.21.162 slave2
10.242.21.163 slave3
10.242.21.164 slave4
10.242.21.165 slave5

Comment: execute "ping localhost" and set the result name instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I try this "ping localhost" the result gives "PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.",this means that the localhost is the same nome "localhost"

Comment: Then replace with the actual IP address